# Adobe Source Sans Pro in a website?

Tags: website-design, fonts, web-fonts

I love the new open source font by Adobe, Source Sans Pro. But I am not sure what will happen if I use the font in a website, and the font isn't installed on the visitor's machine?

Comment: This question would be better fit for http://stackoverflow.com and infact I'm sure it has been aswered there more than once. I would probably recommend http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Comment: Fontsquirrel's generator (by default) throws out all hinting information and replaces it with its own auto-hinting which ... has its problems.  Make sure you test all characters in Windows at various sizes if you're gonna do this.  Much better idea is to use it via [Google Web Fonts](https://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro).

Comment: @thomasrutter Yes. I was recommending fonts quirrel with the assumption that google fonts didn't host this font. Personally I strictly stick to google fonts or web safe fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use webfonts to enable Source Sans Pro so that it displays on other people's browsers.

Thankfully Google host this font.

http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro